# cant see point marker on rviz ros

Tags: python, object-detection, ros, markers

my aim is to follow a green ball with the camera and show the movements of this ball in the view. To do this, I marked the middle of the ball with a marker, but I can't see it in the rviz. The code or rviz does not give any errors, and I am able to visualize /webcam  topic but markers dont show up. What could be the problem? I am using ros neotic Thank you

'''

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import sys

from collections import deque
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker, MarkerArray
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point

import gc
import argparse
import time
import imutils


def camdet():
    bridge = CvBridge()
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", help="Path to the (optional) video file")
    ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", default=64, type=int, help="max buffer size")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
    greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)
    pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

    if not args.get("video", False):
        vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    else:
        vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

    time.sleep(2.0)

    rospy.init_node("object_detection",anonymous=True)

    while True:
        frame = vs.read()
        frame = frame[1] if args.get("video", False) else frame
        if frame is None:
            break

        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
        mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

        cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        center = None
        v = 0
        if len(cnts) > 0:
            c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
            ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
            
            
            M = cv2.moments(c)
           
            center = (int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00']))


            if radius > 10:
                cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (0, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
                v += 1
        pts.append(center)
        
              
        marker = Marker()
        marker.header.frame_id = "base_link"
        marker.ns = "marked"
        marker.id = 0
        marker.type = marker.POINTS
        marker.action = marker.ADD
        marker.scale.x = 1
        marker.scale.y = 1
        marker.scale.z = 0.1
        marker.pose.orientation.x = 0
        marker.pose.orientation.y = 0
        marker.pose.orientation.z= 0
        marker.pose.orientation.w = 1


            
        points = [0,0]
        for i in  range(v):
            p = Point()
            p.x = int(M['m10']/M['m00']) 
            p.y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

            points.clear()
            points.append(p)
            marker.points = points
            print(marker.points)
            marker.pose.position.x = int(M['m10']/M['m00']) 
            marker.pose.position.y = int(M['m01']/M['m00']) 
        
        marker.color.a = 0.4
        marker.color.r = 0.9
        marker.color.g = 0.1
        marker.color.b = 0.2
    
        marker.lifetime = rospy.Duration()
     
        img_pub = rospy.Publisher('webcam/image_raw', Image, queue_size=10)
        rate = rospy.Rate(10)
        msg = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame, encoding="bgr8")
        img_pub.publish(msg)
        marker_pub = rospy.Publisher("marker", Marker, queue_size = 100)   
        marker_pub.publish(marker)
        
    
        
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

        

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        if key == ord('q'):
            break



    if not args.get("video", False):
        vs.stop()
    else:
        vs.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
 
    
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        camdet()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
        
'''
```

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question.

Answer (score 0):

ROS WIKI said "Don't forget to set `color.a = 1` or your marker will be invisible!".